# Parsing an NSString to find and increment numeric values

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I have an string value.

```
NSString *getAllData = @"0,testing,u,4,u";
```

Now I want to increment in all the numeric values in the string e.g. `@"1,testing,u,5,u"`

How can this be done?

Comment: Please let us know what you have tried so far...

Comment: This is what you can do... Create NSArray of this..then loop inside NSArray. check each element of array is of type integer.. if yes, increment & replace element of array... done...

Comment: Long answer: normalize your data. It'll save you from bigger headaches than this down the road.

Comment: upvote? Wow... shocked...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your answer...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *getAllData = @"0,testing,u,4,u";
    NSMutableArray *resultArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    [[getAllData componentsSeparatedByString:@","] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *subString, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if([self isNumeric:subString])
        {
            [resultArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [subString intValue] + 1]];
        }
        else [resultArray addObject:subString];
    }];

    NSString *finalOutput = [resultArray componentsJoinedByString:@","];
    NSLog(@"%@", finalOutput);
}


- (BOOL)isNumeric:(NSString *)aString
{
    NSString *expression = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"^[0-9]*$"];
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:expression options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
    NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:aString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [aString length])];
    return (numberOfMatches != 0);
}
```

Comment: If there is 0^4 value in nsstring then?

Comment: If there is 0^4 value in nsstring then?

Comment: for that just you need to change the regex from `^[0-9]$` to `^[0-9]*$`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `NSScanner` class to find the numbers in the string, and convert them to integers. The `NSMutableString` class can be used to accumulate the output string.

```
- (NSString *)incrementValuesInString:(NSString *)input
{
    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:input];
    [scanner setCharactersToBeSkipped:nil];

    NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString string];

    while ( ![scanner isAtEnd] )
    {
        // copy characters to the result string until a digit is found
        NSString *temp;
        if ( [scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] intoString:&temp] )
            [result appendString:temp];

        // scan the number and increment it
        if ( ![scanner isAtEnd] )
        {
            int value;
            if ( [scanner scanInt:&value] )
                [result appendFormat:@"%d", value + 1];
        }
    }

    return( [result copy] );
}
```